# How to search and rescue missing person in the late Cretaceous?

Tags: technology, time-travel, survival, dinosaurs

Continue from [How to tour Cretaceous Period on economic class?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/59276/how-to-tour-cretaceous-period-on-economic-class).

Say one of my VVIP client got trapped alone in the late Cretaceous Period, and his family wish to recover him alive in one piece. I believe that he must have got outside of the booth when he has unintentionally drops the receiver which activates the time travel leaving him marooned all alone in the lost world.

I've decided to send an Unmanned Aerial Vehicle(UAV) to retrieve him, of course as the maximum passenger capacity is 1 pax. The drone will need to search for the missing person and guide him back to the booth. All time tourists are briefed on the do & don't before leaving for the lost world, they are reminded to never lose the solar powered radio transmitter strapped around their neck and the air from the breathing apparatus should last 72 hours under normal use.

Assuming he has not wandered more than a mile from the rendezvous point and there are dangerous theropods in the vicinity, how could the VVIP had equipped himself to prepare for the challenge such as being stranded in the late Cretaceous period and survive for at least 72 hours until the UAV can guide him back to the proper timeline?

Difficulty: ⭐⭐⭐⭐

How can I improve the reliability and searching capability of the autonomous UAV in this rescue mission? This time no budget constraints but keep it to modern day tech.

Difficulty: ⭐⭐

Assume when there is no occupants the booth is invincible, there is an automatic robot to hang up the receiver when the missing person gets inside the booth or the missing person is found to be dead by the smart UAV. Handwavium shall be applicable exclusively to the time traveling ability.

Comment: "What items does my character need to do X?" is a clearly story-centric question. If you feel the character needs to do X, then give them item Y that makes X easier/possible.

Answer (score 1):

I remember a very detailed and funny description of this kind of survival and rescue in the book series by Jodi Taylor
Just One Damned Thing After Another: The Chronicles of St. Mary’s Book One 
by Jodi Taylor 
Link: http://a.co/7GdXQLN

Essentially, the heroine of the story is trying to rescue several colleagues who were trapped in the Cretaceous.  She attracts them by playing loud music, and fends off a T-Rex during their ensuing rescue.

Hope this is of some help...